# Show posts by slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve specific posts by using slug description.

All posts (in this case products) are stored in "portfolio" where "automotive" is one of the
filters used as a category.

I have already seen some related posts on the web but due to my lack of PHP knowledge couldn't figure it out so far and thought to give it a try here.

Here is the code used. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
// Create a new `WP_Query()` object

$wpcust = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => array('portfolio'),
        'tag_slug__in' => array('automotive'),
        'post__not_in' => array(1366, 1359, 1353),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
        'showposts' => '4' )
    );
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the parameters you can use in your Wordpress Query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

- The `post_type` can be an array or a string.
- The `tag` should be a
  string.
- The `post__not_in` should be an array.
- The `orderby` should
  be a string.
- The `showposts` is DEPRECATED. You need to use
  `posts_per_page` instead. The `posts_per_page` should be an integer.

*posts_per_page (int) - number of post to show per page (available with Version 2.1, replaced showposts parameter). Use 'posts_per_page'=>-1 to show all posts (the 'offset' parameter is ignored with a -1 value). Set the 'paged' parameter if pagination is off after using this parameter.*

Your code should be:

```
$wpcust = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'tag' => 'automotive',
        'post__not_in' => array(1366, 1359, 1353),
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => '4' 
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help :-

```
$wpcust = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'tag_id' => '54',
        'post__not_in' => array(1366, 1359, 1353),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => '4' )
    );
```